# Showing details of previous user ( Okta Dashboard sign out doesn’t remove application tokens )

Tags: okta, okta-api, okta-signin-widget

After I try to launch an app using the Okta dashboard, I have a problem; it displays old user information (perhaps because the local app token is unclear when we sign out of the Okta dashboard).

Scenario

1. Sign in with user A to the Okta dashboard.
2. Use the Okta dashboard to launch my application
3. Exit user A from the Okta dashboard.
4. Sign in with user B to the Okta dashboard.
5. Run my application through the Okta dashboard once more (here it shows me User-A details)

So, is there a way to deal with this circumstance?

**What is expected to happen?**

It should show me the User-B details on my App

**SDK Versions**

@okta/okta-auth-js: ^6.0.0

@okta/okta-react: ^6.4.3

**Execution Environment**

macOS, Google Chrome, React (typescript)

I use [Okta Sign users into your SPA using the redirect model](https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/sign-into-spa-redirect/react/main/)

Thanks!!

Comment: do you use SAML or OIDC SSO with your application?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is on your application side and in your expectations.

OIDC with Okta does not have a way to inform your application, that user A signed out of Okta. You need `logout` flow to be initiated from your application end.

So your app holds a token from user A and never had a chance to know, that in Okta user A logged off.

But my question is: does the fact that a user signed out of Okta mean that their identity changed?! No. So for your app the user is still confirmed legitimate user.

What you are trying to achieve is `session management` which is a responsibility of an application. Okta only confirms/asserts to your app a user's identity.